# How to add a label to simple & Bundle product price?

Tags: product, magento2.2.2, bundled-product, simple-product, special-price

I need to add the Saving percentage label to the product after the price on the category listing page and product details page.

I managed to do this for configurable products by adding the below code to

> /app/design/frontend/theme/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml

```
<span class="price-percentage-pdp price-percentage">
    <?php $percentage = 100 - round(($finalPriceModel->getAmount()->getValue() / $priceModel->getAmount()->getValue())*100); ?>
    <?php echo $percentage ."% OFF"?>
</span>
```

This is working fine.

How & where can I add a special price percentages for simple products & bundle products?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For Simple**

```
/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml
```

override on below path

```
/app/design/frontend/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml
```

**For Bundle**

```
/vendor/magento/module-bundle/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml
```

override on below path

```
/app/design/frontend/theme/Magento_Bundle/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it helped me

Comment: welcome.. happy coading!!